# Sum columns of multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and currently learning arrays.  I'm trying to generate a 5x5 array of random numbers and then sum  the elements of each column (rows 1 to 5) in the 6th row.

As follows:

```
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5 
5 10 15 20 25  (this is what I'm trying to append)
```

My code is currently outputting TWO separate arrays.  The first 5x5 array is correct (in that it's outputting the random numbers, but without the 6th row summing up each of the elements in the column above).  The problem is that it's outputting a SECOND 5x5 array of all 0's.  What I'm trying to achieve is just one matrix.

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int M = 5;
const int N = 5;

int myArray [M] [N] = {0};

void generateArray();
void sumColumns(int [] [M]);
void printSumColumns(int [] [M]);


int main()
{
    generateArray();

    sumColumns(myArray);

    return 0;
}

void generateArray()
{

    // set the seed
    unsigned setSeed = 1023;
    srand(setSeed);

    // generate the matrix using pseudo-random numbers

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            myArray[M][N] = rand() % 100;

            // output the matrix
            cout << left << setw(4) << myArray[M][N] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void sumColumns(int [] [M])
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < M; ++j)
            myArray[i][M] += myArray[i][j];
    }

    printSumColumns(myArray);
}

void printSumColumns(int [] [N])
{
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < M; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < M; j++){
            cout << left << setw(4) << myArray[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Any idea how to just append that 6th row summing up the column elements?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had couple of errors:

- In the indexing of the array.  You had `myArray[m][n] = rand()` while it should has been `myArray[i][j]` - Pay more attention to these, specially [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) errors.
- You also need to add another `row` for the sums so they can be added into your matrix.
- Your random generator was not random. The seed was constant which makes it always the same values of "random" numbers.
- You do not need to pass the array as functions variables in: `void generateArray(); void sumColumns(); void printSumColumns();` - they are already using global variables in their implementations.

**This is the code after-fix**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int M = 5;
const int N = 5;

//M+1 for the sums row
int myArray [M+1] [N] = {0};

//No need to pass any arguments since you're using global vars
void generateArray();
void sumColumns();
void printSumColumns();


int main()
{
    generateArray();    
    sumColumns();    
    return 0;
}

void generateArray()
{

    // set the seed=time for a better rand generation
    srand(time(NULL));

    // generate the matrix using pseudo-random numbers

    for(int i=0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < N; j++)
        {
            myArray[i][j] = rand() % 100;

            // output the matrix
            cout << left << setw(4) << myArray[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl<< endl;
}

void sumColumns()
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < M; ++j)
            myArray[M][j] += myArray[i][j];
    }

    printSumColumns();
}

void printSumColumns()
{
    cout << endl;
    //print the whole matrix with +1 row of sums.
    for(int i=0; i < M+1; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < N; j++){
            cout << left << setw(4) << myArray[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should prefer <ctime> instead of <time.h>

Comment: @wonce could you explain why? I don't spot any differences

Comment: The .h headers place the symbols in the global scope and are provided mainly for C compabilily.

Comment: I've made the changes to my code per AK_'s suggestions (thank you, by the way).  Now, I'm seeing one 5x5 matrix (without that 6th row of sums) and, just beneath, the 6x5 matrix with the 6th row of sums.  Is it possible to have only one 6x5 matrix with the sums? (maybe this is not possible using arrays) .... Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I wasn't thinking.  I just commented out the output in the generateArray() function.  Now, we're left with only the desired 6x5 matrix.  Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `myArray[i][M] += myArray[i][j];` you access out of bounds of the array. When the size is `M`, the valid indices are `0`, `1`, ..., `M-1`.   (Also this would be writing to the 6th column, whereas your description says you want to write to the 6th row).

You cannot append rows to an array in C++, they must have size fixed at compile-time.

Also, the functions should take `int [] [N]`, not `int [] [M]` . (It only works so far because you have `M == N`).

You get two arrays as output because in your `printSumColumns` function you output a value for each entry (see how you have two nested loops, and the output is inside both).

To fix this you could either :

- not use arrays at all (my recommendation) - use `vector`
- declare the array as having 6 rows and 5 columns;  and use the 6th row for storing the sums
- store the sums in a separate 1x5 array
- not store the sums at all, just calculate and print them in one go

Comment: the guy is 'still learning' I don't think `vectors` make any sens to him/her for now.

Comment: I think vectors are easier to learn than C-style arrays. Most programming languages with the concept of "array" include that they can be re-sized, and have their length checked, and be copied by value.  Try explaining exactly why `int [] [M]` is needed in his function parameters...

Comment: agreed but for someone who is still learning I think this is still an advanced topic :-)

Comment: Well.. you have to learn the concept "array" sooner or later, and he seems to want it now... so he should start with the simplest type of array in C++, which is `vector`.  The C-style array can be left for the "advanced topics" stage.